# Permission Denied while trying to run a Python package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-dateutil

I'm trying to use a Python package called `csvkit` on an AWS EC2 machine. I was able to install it after some hiccups, which might be related - running `pip install csvkit` threw an error at

```
with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
    IOERROR: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt'
```

But I was able to install it with some other command.

Now onto the original problem - when I try to run a simple function within the `csvkit` package like `cavstat`, this is the full error output:

```
[username ~]$ csvstat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/csvstat", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 614, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 920, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 815, in resolve
    new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2552, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2537, in _dep_map
    for extra, reqs in split_sections(self._get_metadata(name)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2978, in split_sections
    for line in yield_lines(s):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2252, in yield_lines
    for ss in strs:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2566, in _get_metadata
    for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1589, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1581, in get_metadata
    return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1692, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt'
```

I'm not sure what to even search to see what's the issue. Is this related to `date-utils`? 
I'm fairly new to the Linux world, so editing configuration files and whatnot is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: Did you try to `chomd u+rw /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt`.

Comment: Tried it and got `cannot access '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/re‌​quires.txt' No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a system-wide install via 'pip install csvkit', you'll need sudo privileges for the current user, which is why the install process has borked on modifying the /usr/local/lib/python2.7 structure.

If you're on an AWS instance you've created, sudo privileges should be pretty straightforward to set up for your current user.

If you're looking for a more contained alternative, you could install virtualenv and set up an isolated virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) but virtualenv might be overkill for a throwaway server.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Yep, that definitely helps. So after searching for how to add the ec2-user to have sudo privileges, I came across this: http://serverfault.com/questions/599357/how-does-amazon-ec2-user-get-its-sudo-rights . Am I supposed to delete that last line?

Comment: If you want to give the ec2-user full privileges with no password required, you can add the following line:

ec2-user          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Also, neglected to mention in previous comment: use the 'visudo' command as root to add those privileges. It's also possible to just use the root user for package installs, but that means constantly popping back and forth between users. This is a one time change to make life much easier.

Comment: Wait, can you elaborate on that? I should use `visudo` on editing the file, or `pip install csvkit`?

Comment: Ah, sorry for being vague.

To add sudo privileges for your ec2-user, change to the root user, and run the 'visudo' command, which will open up the sudoers file to edit. It's the safest way to modify configuration.