# Python-dateutil error while running a Python package

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I'm trying to run a function from a Python package called `csvkit`. Function itself is `csvstat`. The error I'm getting is:

> The 'python-dateutil==2.2' distribution was not found and is required by csvkit

I've ran `pip install python-dateutil --upgrade` and apparently it's all up to date.

Looking for suggestions on what to do to fix this problem.

I have another question that might be related: [Permission Denied while trying to run a Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856188/permission-denied-while-trying-to-run-a-python-package)

Comment: What is the output of `pip list | grep dateutil`?

Comment: `python-dateutil (2.4.2)` So it looks like the installer or package is expecting 2.2?

Answer (score 4):

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil==2.2
```

Preferably from inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

you can download the .Whl file of python-dateutil and copy it in script folder of your python location
then open cmd and cd to script location and write below command:
pip install (file.whl)